# How to Get Multiple True Results in IIF Statement in Criteria Section of Query

Tags: ms-access

I am using the input from a form called RunReports to supply the criteria for a query field called `"Active"`.  The input in the form is a combo box also called `"Active"` with three options, `"Yes,"` `"No,"` and `"Both."`  I would like the criteria in the query to vary based on the input in this form combo box. For `"Yes"`, I would like the criteria to be `"Yes"`.  For `"No"`, I would like the criteria to be `"No"`.  For `"Both"`, I would like the criteria to be `"Yes"` or `"No"` meaning that the query should look for both.

```
IIf([Forms]![RunReports]![Active]="Both",Like "*",[Forms]![RunReports]![Active])
```

gives no responses when `"Both"` is selected, as if it is looking for the actual character `*` rather than the wild card it is supposed to be.

```
IIf([Forms]![RunReports]![Active]="Both","Yes" Or "No",[Forms]![RunReports]![Active])
```

when `"Both"` is selected here, it throws the error:

```
"This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.  For example, a numeric expression  may contain too many  complicated elements.  Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables."
```

I get this error even though putting `"Yes"` or `"No"` on separate lines in the criteria works fine.

I can manually place `"Yes"` and `"No"` on separate lines in the criteria to get the correct `"Both"` response as well as the individual `"Yes"` and `"No"` to get their corresponding responses.  Using `Like"*"` in the criteria field also works.  When I try this in an `IIF` statement placed in the criteria field, they do not work the same way as they do by themselves.

Is there a way to set up my query criteria to pull all records with both `"Yes"` or  `"No"` responses as indicated by my form using an `IIF` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Like iif([Forms]![RunReports]![Active]="Both",”*",[Forms]![RunReports]![Active])

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,but that gives an invalid string error, but this works:
IIf([Forms]![RunReports]![Active]="Both","Yes",[Forms]![RunReports]![Active]) Or IIf([Forms]![RunReports]![Active]="Both","No",[Forms]![RunReports]![Active])